# Password protect GitLab pages with htpasswd

Tags: gitlab, .htpasswd

Is there a way to password protect a website published using [GitLab pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/pages/README.html)?

I tried adding an `.htpasswd` file to the root of the `/pages` directory, but that just makes the file available to everyone who goes to https://username.gitlab.io/mysite/.htpasswd.

Comment: hi, did u find any solution?

Comment: its not wise to make a .htpasswd file accessible by the web. did you find any solution to password protect the gitlab pages project?

Comment: @JuHwon I couldn't find a solution that didn't involve using AWS or Heroku. But this feature may be added to GitLab EE at some point in the future: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/624.

Comment: To expand on the Heroku option, you could check out [jekyll-auth](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-auth).

Answer (score 3):

GitLab now supports access control for pages in case of self managed GitLab instances:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/pages/#access-control

> Pages access control is currently disabled by default. To enable it, you must:
>
> 1. Enable it in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
>
>    `gitlab_pages['access_control'] = true`
> 2. [Reconfigure GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/restart_gitlab.html#omnibus-gitlab-reconfigure)